# Json Custom Converter registration seems to overwrite global options System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net-core, system.text.json

I have this in my program.cs

```
builder.Services.Configure<JsonOptions>(options =>
 {
     //options.SerializerOptions.Converters.Add(new CustomJsonConverterForType());
     options.SerializerOptions.ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.IgnoreCycles;
     options.SerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode;
 })
```

Without the custom type converter my ReferenceHandler works and is applied as expected.

When I add the custom converter for System.Type I get the cyclic references exception back as if somehow the registration of the converter resets the defaults ?

My convert is as it describes, is for handling system.type serialization.

I would expect that the global settings still apply but introducing the new converter re-surfaces the cyclic error.

Comment: *When I add the custom converter for System.Type I get the cyclic references exception back as if somehow the registration of the converter resets the defaults ?* -- might you please [edit] your question to share a [mcve], specifically a converter that demonstrates the problem?  See also [ask].  Thanks!